# error while retrieving the date from mongoDB - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java-driver

I have created a spring application , where I am sending some date to mongoDB which includes date also. I am using below date pattern.

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
date = cal.getTime();
```

I am using getter setter for storing and retrieving the data from mongoDB. 
which is of type Date. I am able to store the data fine. But while retrieving  it shows `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I saw data in mongoDB, date is stored as object.
Any idea how we can store the date as date so we can do query based on timestamp

Comment: What are you using to retrieve the data from MongoDB?

Comment: Criteria criteria = new Criteria();   criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("_id").is("12"),Criteria.where("searchQueryAnalysis.searchKeyword").is("iphone1"));

MainClickStreamData mcsd=   mongoOperation.findOne(query, MainClickStreamData.class);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried

> Date date = new Date();

And then pushed the date as it is . No need to change it .